# Spaces: How to set an app to appear in every space but one?

Tags: spaces

Spaces lets you set up certain applications to open in a specific space, no particular space or all of them. Sometimes though I wished to have a space where my apps that usually would appear in all other spaces wouldn't go.

For example, if I had six spaces, and had iTunes, Skype and Colloquy set to go on all spaces, I'd like to set space 6 as off-limits for those three apps. They wouldn't be moved to space 6 when switching to it.

Is there a way to do this? I have been searching the web but couldn't find any tool/setting editing that lets me do that. Is it just impossible? (maybe i just haven't looked hard enough?) Thanks in advance for your help!